# Problem from Red Book

Tags: integer-lattices

The following problem is from The Red Book (list of practice problems for undergraduate mathematics competition).
Let $k$ denote a positive integer. Determine the number $N(k)$ of triples $(x,y,z)$ of integers
satisfying
$$\begin{cases} |x|\leq k, & |y|\leq k, & |z|\leq k,\\
|x-y|\leq k, & |y-z|\leq k, & |z-x|\leq k.
\end{cases}$$
A solution is as follows:
Let $N(k,i)$ be the number of lattice points satisfying the given conditions, and the further condition $z=i$, $-k \leq i \leq k$. Then $N(k,0)=(2k+1)^2 -k(k+1)$ (the $(2k+1)^2$ lattice points on the $x,y$ plane without the points lying above the line
$y=k$ or below the line $y=-k$). If $z=1$, then we need to subtract the bottom row of points (there are $k+1$), and
the left column (an additional $k$ of them), for a total of $2k+1$ points. If $z=2$, we need to subtract
another $2k+1$ points. In general, for $z=i$ we need to subtract
$(2k+1)i$ points. In other words,
$$N(k,i)=(2k+1)^2-k(k+1)-(2k+1)i, 1\leq i \leq k.$$
Since the configuration will be symmetric for negative values
of $z$,
$N(k,i)=N(k,-i)$.
Hence
$$N(k)=N(k,0)+2\sum_{i=1}^kN(k,i) = (2k+1)^2-k(k+1)+2\sum_{i=1}^k((2k+1)^2-k(k+1)-(2k+1)i)=4k^3+6k^2+4k+1.$$
This proof is not too complicated but not very straightforward either.
Here is my question. The answer can be re-written as $(k+1)^4-k^4$. This makes me wonder
if there is a really simple proof using some geometric interpretation in four dimensions.

Comment: Why would you need four dimension? I believe three is enough. For a given value of $k$, the first three equations means we have a cube of side length 2k centered at origin. We want a subset of the solid region which satisfies the above eqtn

Comment: Yes, and my proof is essentially that: first look at the slice at $z=0$, then look at the "first floor" $z=1$, and then add up all the floors to get the answer. But my point is that the answer $(k+1)^4 -k^4$ seems to say it could be obtained from some 4-dimensional interpretation.

Comment: I will return to this uqestion in time.